# EXECUTE permission denied subtext_GetBlogStats after fresh install

Tags: subtext

I have just installed a fresh instance of SubText via the Web installer, I can open the new site up, login to the http:///HostAdmin no problem, but when I login to http:///Admin I get the error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on
>   the object 'subtext_GetBlogStats',
>   database 'subtext', schema 'dbo'.

I could just open the database up to allow the user to have all permissions, but that's kinda crappy, I could add the permission to the single stored procedure, but then I don't know what other permissions might not be set right.

What database permissions should have been set for a correct subtext installation?

I'm not exactly sure if this should be asked here, on serverfault.com or on webapps.stackexchange.com, so sorry if it's in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Simone, member of the subtext team.
I know this problem happens from time to time.
The SQL Script that grants permission to the SPs is correct, and in fact most of the times the permissions are set correctly.
Setting the permissions to that SP will fix your problem.

Let me know if you have any other problem
Simone